# SQL Query - how to filter dates rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried to find an answer to my problem via the search option but I failed to find a 100% fit solution.

I have the next table output:

```
vpo_number  location_name   current_task_id VPO_TIME                Shelf_Time
Y046006F    FLOOR           971516          2020-11-30 05:00:32.560 2020-11-20 07:01:56.830
**Y046006F  FLOOR           971516          2020-11-30 05:00:32.560 2020-12-23 12:08:55.183**
Y046006F    FLOOR           971516          2020-11-30 05:00:32.560 2020-11-18 21:34:21.473
```

How can I edit my query that I will get only the row with the most recent update under "Shelf_Time"

Thanks,

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical method is to use `row_number()` to get one row per group.  Assuming you want one row per `vpo_number`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by vpo_number order by shelf_time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you just want the most recent row in the table, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by shelf_time desc
limit 1;
```